# Cant seem to match Exact string with Preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Im trying to exactly match a string using the preg_replace function in php.
I only want to match instances that have a single '@' symbol.
I also require a variable to be passed in as a pattern.

```
$x = "@hello, @@hello, @hello, @@hello"
$temp = '@hello'

$x = preg_replace("/".$temp."/", "replaced", $x);
```

the result should just be:

```
$x = "replaced, @@hello, replaced, @@hello"
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a negative [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<!@)` that will fail a match if the `$temp` is preceded with `@` (or, in plain words, if there is a `@` before `@hello`, do not match it):

```
$x = "@hello, @@hello, @hello, @@hello";
$temp = '@hello';
$x = preg_replace("/(?<!@)".$temp."/", "replaced", $x);
echo $x;
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/9s3L82)

And here is [a regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nY6tS1/1)

Also, if you have whole word boundary at the end, append `\b` to the end of the pattern just to ensure you do not replace `@helloween`:

```
"/(?<!@)".$temp."\\b/"
```

Comment: Don't forget `preg_quote()` on `$temp` if it's dynamic.